# ADF throwing java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: oracle-adf, oracleportal

Our server has been upgraded as below,

Weblogic Server from version 10.3.3 to 10.3.6
Portal 11g Midtier from version 11.1.1.3   to 11.1.1.7
Portal repository (Portal-schemas in the database) from version 11.1.1.3 to version 11.1.1.6

We are getting following error on several pages, help appreciated

*java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.config.rich.XmlRenderResponseInvocationHandler.(XmlRenderResponseInvocationHandler.java:50)
  at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.config.rich.RegistrationConfigurator.getExternalContext(RegistrationConfigurator.java:181)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.GlobalConfiguratorImpl.getExternalContext(GlobalConfiguratorImpl.java:368)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl$CacheRenderKit.(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:86)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl.getFacesContext(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.portlet.bridge.adf.application.ADFBridgePortlet.doFacesRequest(ADFBridgePortlet.java:344)
  at fi.luottokunta.partner.util.BridgePortlet.doFacesRequest(BridgePortlet.java:52)*

at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: oracle.portlet.server.containerimpl.ContainerIllegalArgumentException: Content type ***"text/xml;charset=utf-8"*** is not allowed in current context.
  at oracle.portlet.server.containerimpl.RenderResponseImpl.setContentType(RenderResponseImpl.java:269)
  at oracle.portlet.bridge.adf.application.ResourceResponseWrapper.setContentType(ResourceResponseWrapper.java:41)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.config.rich.XmlRenderResponseInvocationHandler.(XmlRenderResponseInvocationHandler.java:44)
  at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.config.rich.RegistrationConfigurator.getExternalContext(RegistrationConfigurator.java:181)

Additional information, The issue might be arising due to ADF components.

For example in below sample if we remove the selectionListener component from jspx the application works without error. SP500.jspx

```
<af:table contentDelivery="immediate" width="915" var="user" value="#{viewScope.SP500.sortableModel}" rowBandingInterval="0"
                                  rendered="#{viewScope.SP500.renderResults}" autoHeightRows="12" immediate="true" binding="#{viewScope.SP500.userTable}"
                                  rowSelection="multiple" selectionListener="#{viewScope.SP500.selectionListener}" columnStretching="last"
                                  disableColumnReordering="true">
                            <af:column styleClass="datacolumns" minimumWidth="155" width="200px" headerText="#{msg.SP500_F016}" sortable="true"
                                       sortProperty="uid">
                                <af:commandLink text="#{user.uid}" action="#{viewScope.SP500.viewUser}">
                                    <af:setPropertyListener from="#{user}" to="#{requestScope.viewUser}" type="action"/>
                                </af:commandLink>
                            </af:column>
```

SP500.java

```
public void selectionListener(final SelectionEvent selectionEvent) {
    //Trigger a check of whether the delete button is enabled
    AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(deleteButton);
}
```

Comment: This seems rather a integration problem between ADF and Portal. From ADF's perspective, this code is valid.

Comment: Hi Florin, thank you for the reply. The code is correct because it was working fine in old version of portal server. We are facing this issue after the up gradation of portal servers. Do you have any idea what kind of integration problem causing this issue ?

Comment: No, sorry, I am not familiar with Portal.